# How to get new messages on bottom of the list view

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I'm fetching the messages from fire base new messages are appears randomly in the list view how I can set the new messages on the bottom of my list view in flutter?

Here is the code:

```
 body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                List<MyMessageContainer> messageWidget = [];
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                    ),
                  );
                }
                final messagesDoc = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
                for (var messageData in messagesDoc) {
                  final messageBody = messageData.data();
                  final messageText = messageBody['text'];
                  final messageSender = messageBody['sender'];
                  final msg = MyMessageContainer(
                    message: messageText,
                    sender: messageSender,
                    isCurrentUser: messageSender == user.email ? true : false,
                  );
                  messageWidget.add(msg);
                }
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    reverse: true,
                    children: messageWidget,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firestore has no built-in way to identify "new" messages. If you want that, you'll have to store a value in each document with a timestamp.**

When you've done that, you can get them in the correct order in your code with:

```
_firestore.collection('messages').orderBy("timestampField").snapshots()
```

Comment: Not working when I used orderBy all messages are disappeared. Another solution??

Comment: Did you add a `timestampField` to the documents, as I said in my first sentence? Without that, the query will indeed not match anything as Firebase has no built-in mechanism to query documents on when they were created/edited.

Comment: Yes I passed timestampField  as String argument in orderBy then all the messages are disappeared .

Comment: Please read my answer carefully again, especially these first two sentences: **Firestore has no built-in way to identify "new" messages. If you want that, you'll have to store a value in each document with a timestamp.** Only once you've done that, will the query start to work.